# How can I detect the requests made by the browser to fetch the TS files while playing a HLS video?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I wanted to know what point the user is in a live stream with high accuracy , but to determine that i just want a general solution which would work for safari as well as 3rd party hls libraries , one way would be to know which TS file is being requested by the player . but im unable to even detect the m3u8 calls or even the ts file requests. I have tried almost all questions which are regarding intercepting of fetch calls or xmlhttprequests , they dont seem to work for that. how can i approach this issue ?

I have tried answers which are regarding intercepting of fetch calls or xmlhttprequests  or adding event listeners on the xml http request or the fetch function, they don't seem to work on these specific requests.

Comment: What service is producing the live stream? What player are you using?

Comment: @ToddSharp creating HLS using ffmpeg. and IVS player

Comment: Check my answer below. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the Amazon IVS player (which you mentioned you are using in the comments above), you can listen for the `IVSPlayer.MetadataEventType.ID3` event and retrieve the `trans_c` timestamp from the ID3 event:

```js
window.ivsPlayer.addEventListener(IVSPlayer.MetadataEventType.ID3, (evt) => {
  const segmentMetadata = evt.find((tag) => tag.desc === 'segmentmetadata');
  const segmentMetadataInfo = JSON.parse(segmentMetadata.info[0]);
  const timestamp = segmentMetadataInfo['transc_s'];
  const timestampWithMs = timestamp * 1000;
  console.log(timestampWithMs);
  console.log(new Date(timestamp));
});
```

More info about this [here](https://dev.to/aws/amazon-ivs-live-stream-playback-with-chat-replay-13d5). You can also use [getPosition()](https://aws.github.io/amazon-ivs-player-docs/1.16.0/web/classes/mediaplayer.html#getposition) on the IVS player if you are looking for how long the local video has been playing on the current page, but that may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you for the answer , but this solution works only for Interactive video service generated HLS , when you generate your own HLS live stream the get live latency does not work , also about the insertion of ID3 tags , we would rather not modify the binary of the video file .